# How can I add what url a form is coming from into mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an html form that I have included in several different pages and I want to know how to make the mysql database show which url(landing page) each entry came from. What's the best way to do this? I've searched but haven't found a way to make it work.

I'm using php and mysql.

Comment: use Google Analytics (or similar solution). Don't re-invent the wheel

Comment: Your web server may be logging Referrer information. That's the page that lead users to the current page. You can use Google Analytics, as @Raptor mentioned, or use AWStats to generate web server stats rather easily

Comment: I was able to resolve it using input type="hidden". :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
echo "DOCUMENT_ROOT : ".$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
echo "REQUEST_URI : ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use following:---

```
$pageURL = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
echo $pageURL.
```

It will help you.